# How do I use teh replit Database in a js file?

Tags: node.js, database, replit

I have a very basic setup of replit Database in my index.js using Node.js.

I would like to use this db in another js file in another module. How do I do so?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'));
const port = 3000

const Database = require("@replit/database");
const db = new Database();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});

app.get('/projection', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/routes/projection.html')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}`)
})

async function setKey(key, value) {
    await db.set(key, value);
};

async function getKeyValue(key) {
    let value = await db.get(key);
    return value;
};

async function deleteKey(key) {
    await db.delete(key);
};

async function listKeys() {
    let keys = await db.list()
    return keys;
};

async function listKeyPrefix(prefix) {
    let matches = await db.list(prefix);
    return matches;
};

setKey("stories", ["1"]);
listKeys().then((keys) => console.log(keys));
```

This is my index.js file and I would like to use this db in another js file